Power BI Embedded Maps Fix
I have an issue when maps are working perfectly fine in the pbi web app: https://app.powerbi.com/ but it is not rendering in embedded version (iframed) in UI. Seems it has some infinite loop problem, when I checked console it goes crazy and requests are non stop:

and maps show blank..

SO can host images directly. Do not post links to off-site image hosts.  Moved it for you.  Check the relevance of tags too; to he "embedded" tag was not appropriate in this context.
